# JavaScript Switch Case Statement Situation

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
switch (command) {
  case "greeting": { console.log('hello'); } break;
  case "eat": { console.log('so gooood'); } break;
  case "drink": { console.log('so gooood'); } break;
  case "crunch": { console.log('so gooood'); } break;
}
```

but the last 3 cases are outputing the same code, and I wanted to find a more organized way to do so. Does anyone know of a good technique I can use to make it work? Something like the following code:

```
switch (command) {
  case "greeting" : { console.log('hello') } break;
  case "eat", "drink", "crunch": {console.log('so gooood') } break;
}
```

The previous code does not work, but I was trying to demonstrate what I'm trying to do with the code. Basically group up a bunch of values for command that would make 1 specific action to take place instead of having 3 separate  cases for the same action. Would anyone know how I might go about doing that?

Comment: You could easily have answered this yourself by reading the manual for `switch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: thanks for the response @deceze I don't believe this is one of those situations. I didn't think there was a built in method in switch to get this done and though if conditionals and hacky tricks were used to get it done, and sometimes when trying to do more complexed things you forget about the simple solutions, which is why I feel it wasn't warrented, though I understand your reasoning. I will be giving you the accepted answer when the timelimit ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fall-through cases:

```
switch (command) {
  case "greeting":
    console.log('hello');
    break;

  case "eat":
  case "drink":
  case "crunch":
    console.log('so gooood');
    break;
}
```

`switch` will start running code at the first matching `case` **and continue until it encounters a `break`.** That's the reason you're putting in `break`s, so the following cases won't run. If you leave out the `break`, you get fall-through cases which work as you expect.

The `{}` inside `case` were unnecessary by the way.